# Hermite interpolation code in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation, hermite-polynomials

This is my MATLAB code for divided differences and Hermite interpolation, but it doesn't work properly. Could you take a look at it? Thank you.

*I'm sorry for the layout, but it's the best I could do.*

```
function [F,X] = diffdivher(x,fx,df)

    X=[];

    for i=1:length(x)
        X=[X,x(i),x(i)];
    end

    for i=1:length(f);
        F=[F,f(i),f(i)];
    end

    n=length(x)-1;
    N=2*n+1;

    for i=N:-2:3
        F(i)=(F(i)-F(i-1))/(X(i)-X(i-1));
    end

    for k=2:N
        for i=N+1:-2:k+1
            F(i)=(F(i)-F(i-1))/(X(i)-X(i-k));
        end
    end
end

function [Pval] = herhor(x,f,df,xval)
    X=[];

    for i=1:length(x)
        X=[X,x(i),x(i)];
    end

    dd=diffdivher(x,f,df);

    for i=1:length(xval)
        Pval(i)=dd(end);
        for j=length(dd)-1:-1:1
            Pval(i)=dd(j)+(xval(i)-X(j))*(Pval(i));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What exactly is your function *supposed* to do? In Hermite interpolation you may want to impose conditions of any number of derivatives at any number of the given points, which makes me suspicious of the original function declaration from the start before I even get into the code itself. Unless you're doing something relatively narrow, for example interpolating exactly one derivative at each of the interpolation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume your formulae are correct, and just give some MATLAB observations. For your `diffdivher` function:

- Are you storing each function in its own *.m file?
- You need a `F=[];` before using `F` in your second for-loop.
- Second for-loop: that semi-colon after `length(f)` really shouldn't be there.
- Your `diffdivher` function receives a `fx` and a `df`, but in your second for-loop you are using a `f` that came right of nowhere.
- First two for-loops: if you are iterating over the entries of `x` and `f`, then it is easier to just assume `x` and `f` are row vectors, then access each entry as `for y=x`,  `for z=f`. Also, not the most practical way of sortedly duplicating the entries of a vector; simply do `X=[x;x](:)';`.
- Your third for-loop is really not that necessary, you can just do `u=N:-2:3;`, then `F(u)=(F(u)-F(u-1))./(X(u)-X(u-1));`. Notice the dot before the slash. Similarly for the inner loop of your fourth for-loop.

Observations for your `herhor` function:

- You need to declare the length of `Pval` before accessing `dd(end)` to each entry.
- Your first for-loop has the same issues as the fourth item listed above.